# am trying to learn Linked list and i don't know why there is a loop in my object

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I expected it to run once but there is a loop of objects inside obj2.b one after the other. why won't it calling it once?:

```
const test2 = function (numb) {
//making an object
  let obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };

    let obj2 = {
    d: numb,
    e: null,
  };
  let obj3 = obj2;
  obj3.b = obj2;
  console.log(obj3);
};
test2(3);
```

Comment: `let obj2 = obj1;` is superfluous since you reassign `obj2` right away. `obj1` is just discarded, so what’s the point of defining it? What do you mean by “calling it once”? What exactly do you expect to happen and why?

Comment: I just want to know what whats happening. the out put is {d: 3, e: null, b: {…}} and the B is a never ending object. why won't it assign b to {d: 3, e: null, b: {…}} once. why is it looping?  `also am sorry for not explaining enough this is my first time asking is stack`

Comment: Ah, I see. You assigned `obj2.b` as `obj3`, but `obj3` and `obj2` are identical. You then log `obj2`. `obj2.b` points back to `obj2` itself. Simpler example would be `const obj = {}; obj.b = obj; console.log(obj);` — same thing.

Comment: yes! but why is it looping? wait is it this recursion? i didnt get in that topic yet

Comment: No, it’s not recursion. It’s just a reference pointing to something that contains the reference. If you’re in San Francisco and you see a sign that says “This way to San Jose” and you decide to follow the sign, but in San Jose you find another sign that says “This way to San Francisco” and you follow this sign, too, then you’ll end up back in San Francisco, where you’ll find the first sign pointing to San Jose again — “why is it looping?”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Initializing objects in JS

In JavaScript objects are assigned by reference. This means that `let obj3 = obj2` causes both `obj3` and `obj2`
to point to the same object. That is, if you change `obj3` you will change the memory `obj2` references to (as they reference to the same place), thus change `obj2`. In short – **`obj2` and `obj3` is the same object!**. To visualize:

```js
let obj1 = {a: 0};
let obj2 = obj1;
//obj1 and obj2 = {a: 0};

obj2.b = 1;
//obj1 and obj2 = {a: 0, b: 1};
```

### The reason you get circular reference

Having in mind how objects work in JavaScript you can quickly work out that in fact, initializing `obj2` as a value of `obj3.b` is the same as doing `obj3.b = obj3` what is quite obviously a cycle. As every time you assign `obj3` you must also assign it to `obj3.b` and then to `obj3.b.b` and so on infinitely.

## Initializing two separate objects

If initializing object that is supposed to be a copy of another the standard way doesn't work as expected, how to do it properly? The simplest way is to use `Object.assign()` on an empty object, this way we create an entirety new reference to an entirely new object and via that new reference we assign all the data.

```js
let obj1 = {a: 0};
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
//obj1 = {a: 0}
//obj2 = {a: 0}

obj2.b = 1;
//obj1 = {a: 0}
//obj2 = {a: 0, b: 1}
```

### How to fix the function then?

Instead of defining `obj2` as `obj3` using `=` (what as you know now, will reference them both to the same object), use the method mentioned above:

```js
const test2 = function (numb) {
//making an object
  let obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };

    let obj2 = {
    d: numb,
    e: null,
  };
  
  let obj3 = {};
  obj3 = Object.assign(obj3, obj2);
  /** 
    * You can do it in one line too
    * let obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj2);
    */

  obj3.b = obj2;
  console.log(obj3); 
};

test2(3); 
//{ d: 3, e: null, b: { d: 3, e: null } }
```